# How to modify shortcuts in IntelliJ Idea's switcher?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

IntelliJ has a switcher utility (default key combination: ctrl+tab) that displays, among others, a list of windows:

[image]

Some windows have a number/letter shortcut assigned and others don't. How can I assign a number/letter shortcuts to Maven Projects and Terminal? I've tried to search for `switcher` in Preferences, but I couldn't find any helpful settings as of version `2017.3.2`.

Comment: It's not possible to confighure this list, but these items should be automatically mapped to M and T letters (by the first letter in item name). Could you check it with IDEA 2017.3.3?